# how to inject store in service ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I tried to inject the store from the initializer without success, so I use lookup on init in my service, but I don't like it too much, I would rather keep things separated and put the injection in the initializer...

> Ember      : 1.11.1
>
> Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.16.1
>
> jQuery     : 1.11.2

**NOT WORKING:Initializer**

```
//app/initializers/initializer-store.js
export default {
  name: 'initializer-store',
  after: 'store',

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    application.inject('service:mtg-level-service', 'store', 'store:main');
  }
};
```

**WORKING:Service**

```
//app/services/mtg-level-service.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  availableIn: ['controllers', 'routes'],
  store: null,

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set('store', this.container.lookup("store:main"));
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh, and your initializer might need to be executed before the service, you might have a race condition there.

Comment: I'll try to check that thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of Ember v1.10:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({  
  store: Ember.inject.service('store')
});
```

Comment: note that in that context it is `this.get('store')` instead of `this.store`

Comment: how do you do it inside an integration test? **this.inject.service('store')** is null

Comment: the name parameter is optional and defaults to the property's name, so in this case `store: Ember.inject.service()` works the same