# Ember Service To Component

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a service which I'm calling via a component using Ember.inject

app/notifications/service.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service('store'),
  notifications: function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('notification');
  },
});
```

Then my app/components/app-notifications/component.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  notifications: Ember.inject.service('notifications'),
});
```

Then my component template at /app/components/app-notifications/template.hbs

```
{{notifications}}
<ul>
  {{#each notifications as |notification|}}
     <li>{{notification.title}} <small>{{moment-from-now dateAdded}}</small>     </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But I can't get it to show the data from my model? I can't seem to find much info on this in the docs, so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: The `store` is a service too, so you don't need to use it in another service. Also, `store.findAll` returns a promise and in the service there isn't enough time to solve it. Ember waits for promises to be solved in the `model` of the `routes`.

Comment: Apparently to get the ember data store inside a service I have to call it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881771/how-to-inject-store-in-service-ember-js

So for the second part, does this mean I need to call an afterModel or a .findAll('notification').then(function() {?

Comment: You can return more than one model from the route with ```Ember.RSVP.hash({})```

Comment: I don't want to return a model on the route, I'd rather keep in in the service->component

Comment: Please don't put answers into the question. I've added your answer as a [wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49873984/542251) if you'd prefer to self answer ping me and I'll delete the wiki below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it necessary to implement `notifications` as a service?

The common way to do the job is to use a computed property:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  notifications: Ember.computed( function () {
    return this.store.findAll('notification');
  })
});
```

Comment: From discussions with others it seemed the right way to go. It basically sits on the application and is shown across every page in the admin. The plan is to use a socket and have real time notifications.

Comment: Ok, so I got it working with

    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Service.extend({
      store: Ember.inject.service('store'),
      notifications: function() {
        return this.get('store').findAll('notification');
      }.property(),
    });

Answer (score 0):

[Solution from OP:](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32993334/2)

Ok, so I got it working with

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service('store'),
  notifications: function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('notification');
  }.property(),
});
```